# Scala, cats - how to do not use Applicative[F] explicity?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, applicative

I would like to use `Applicative[F]` in some other way then explicity. Currently I have a simple code:

```
class BettingServiceMock[F[_] : Async] extends BettingService[F] {    
      override def put(bet: Bet): F[Bet] = {
        for {
          created <- Bet(Some(BetId(randomUUID().toString)), bet.stake, bet.name).pure
        } yield created
      }
    }
```

`Bet` is just a simple `case class`. I use method `pure` explicity to return `F[Bet]`. Is there some way to do not it like this way (to do not call `pure` method explicity)?
I tried to do something like this:

```
class BettingServiceMock[F[_] : Async] (implicit a:Applicative[F]) extends BettingService[F] {

  override def put(bet: Bet): F[Bet] = {
    for {
      created <- Bet(Some(BetId(randomUUID().toString)), bet.stake, bet.name)
    } yield created
  }
}
```

It did not help, because I got an error: 
`value map is not a member of model.Bet <- (Some(BetId(randomUUID().toString)), bet.stake, bet.name)`

I would like to discover some good practise in `Cats` that's way I'm asking about it. I do not thnik so that explicity call methids like `pure` is  good practise. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, why do you think it's a bad practice. That's a common `Applicative` syntax. If you want some "magic" automatically lifts your value `Bet` to `Applicative[Bet]` then you would need sort of implicit conversion and that would be **really bad practice**.

You take a look at the scaladoc example of `Applicative` https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/Applicative.scala

```
Applicative[Option].pure(10)
```

Here the `Applicative[Option]` instance was summoned by `apply[F[_]](implicit instance: Applicative[F])` which is automatically generated by simulacrum's `@typeclass`.